# Symfony2 - how to insert values into two different tables with one form in doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm sure that this question has been asked before but I'm finding it difficult to find a solution that pertains to my exact issue so I am hoping someone can help me out.

Basically, I have two tables, one called "pet" and one called "customer_pet". These two tables are linked so that I can assign pets to specific people (customers). However I find that if I add the customer id into the form (which is not a field in the pet table) that it does not persist anything. I'm having difficulties with the different types of table and column association in doctrine I think.

In my Pet entity, I have the following:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Customer", inversedBy="pet", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_pet",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pet_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $customer_id;
```

But I am unsure how to map it back in my customer_pet entity. The customer_pet table simply contains pet_id and customer_id. The pet_id is generated when a pet is added and the customer_id is passed through the form in a hidden field.

I'm not overly familiar with table associations in doctrine so any help is appreciated. If anyone needs any other code snippets please ask.

Here is my addPet() method:

```
/**
     * Add pet
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Pet $pet
     * @return Customer
     */
    public function addPet(\AppBundle\Entity\Pet $pet)
    {
        $this->pet[] = $pet;

        return $this;
    }
```

Thank you in advance
Michael

Comment: Does your customer entity have an `addPet()` method?

Comment: Yes, it does. I've added it to the question

Comment: Can you post the code for your form?

Comment: Please post all entities what you want to relate, and form code could be helpfull to.

Comment: This [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) might help you

Answer (score 1):

1)Declare all the tables.
2)Create the form.
3)Send to multiple tables.
4)Persist data.

```
use AppBundle\Entity\site;
use AppBundle\Entity\nba;
```

1)Declare all the tables.

```
 $site = new site;
 $nba = new nba;
```

2)Create form

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($site)




    ->add('site_id', IntegerType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
    ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px'), 'choices' => $output))
    ->add('team', ChoiceType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px'), 'choices' => $nbat))
```

3)Insert into multiple tables.

```
        $site_id = $form['site_id']->getData();
        $category = $form['category']->getData();
        $team = $form['team']->getData();




        $site->setSiteId($site_id);
        $site->setCategory($category);
        $nba->setWinner($team);
```

4)Persist data

```
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($site);
            $em->persist($nba);
            $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to configure the two entities: Pet and Customer. The other table - `customer_pet` - is a so-called [join-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Doctrine does not need an Entity mapping for this table. You need to configure an association mapping to make Doctrine aware of the relationship between Customers and Pets. In this specific case you can use the [Many-To-Many, Bidirectional association](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional), meaning one Customer can have many Pets, and one Pet can have many Customers.
More or less:

- in Customer entity

  ```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Pet", inversedBy="customers")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customer_pet")
   **/
  private $pets;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->pets = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
  }
  ```
- in Pet entity:

  ```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Customer", mappedBy="pets")
   **/
  private $customers;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->customers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
  }
  ```

Then your `createPetAndSetCustomerAction` could look like this:

```
public function createPetAndSetCustomerAction($idCustomer)
{
    $pet = new Pet();
    $pet ->setName('Fluffy');

    $customer = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Customer')
        ->find($idCustomer);

    $pet->getCustomers()->add($customer);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($pet);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Created pet ' . $pet->getName() . ' and set customer ' . $customer->getDescription());
}
```

We're speaking about some basic concepts here and I really recommend you read the [Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) chapter of the Symfony Book two or three times to fully understand these concepts.

Comment: Thank you - I will try this out. I'm aware that this is probably a basic concept, but even though I've been working with Symfony2 for a while, some of the Doctrine stuff does sometimes confuse me!